# Echo cancel and noise reduction - how to use WebRTC echo cancel engine with VLC, Gstreamer, Mplayer, FFmpeg?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, vlc-media-player, mplayer, gstreamer

How to use WebRTC echo cancel with VLC, Gstreamer, Mplayer, FFmpeg?

e.g:

```
vlc alsa://plughw:0,0

gst-launch-0.10 alsasrc device=hw:0 ! autoaudiosink

arecord -D hw:0 -r 44100 -c 2 -f S16_LE | aplay -
```